# Convert a string list which contains a real numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a string, which contains a list of real numbers, for example, `'[0.0, 6.5, 3.0]'`

How can I convert it to list of real numbers?

In my python program I read a csv file and there is a column with color triplets. When I get them, I can't work with them, because they aren't lists with real numbers. I tried to convert, but when I go through the list there is a mistake, because the point that separates the integer and fractional part is not a number.

```
    if j == 'color':
        color_triple = []
        triple = ''.join(lines[i][j])
        for i_ in range(1, len(triple)):
            index = i_
            while triple[index] != ',':
                color = ''
                color += triple[i_]
                index += 1
            color_triple.append(float(color))
            i_ = index
```

I want to have a list `[0.0, 6.5, 3.0]` and work with elements of list as they are float.

Comment: `ast.literal_eval(yourstring)`

Comment: @PatrickArtner This seems like a more established duplicate candidate [Convert string representation of list to list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894269/convert-string-representation-of-list-to-list)

Comment: @Will the other one includes the `float`y part as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works

```
string = '[5.0, 0.9, 0.4]'
arr = eval(string)

print(arr)
```

But the output is

```
[5.0, 0.90000000000000002,0.40000000000000002]
```

You would have to do some post processing

**EDIT:**

As @ThiefMaster suggested, you can use Abstract Syntax Trees.

```
import ast

string = "[5.0, 9.0, 0.3]"
arr = ast.literal_eval(string)

print(arr)
```

Output:

```
[5.0, 9.0, 0.3]
```

More info on ast:

> `ast.literal_eval(node_or_string)`   Safely evaluate an expression
>   node or a string containing a Python literal or container display. The
>   string or node provided may only consist of the following Python
>   literal structures: strings, bytes, numbers, tuples, lists, dicts,
>   sets, booleans, and None.
>
> This can be used for safely evaluating strings containing Python
>   values from untrusted sources without the need to parse the values
>   oneself. It is not capable of evaluating arbitrarily complex
>   expressions, for example involving operators or indexing.
>
> **Warning: It is possible to crash the Python interpreter with a sufficiently large/complex string due to stack depth limitations in
>   Python’s AST compiler. Changed in version 3.2: Now allows bytes and
>   set literals.**
>   *source: https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html*

Answer (score -1):

This could be overkill, but what about processing that string with a regex pattern? Below code works for what I believe your usage would be.

```
import re

def main():
    pattern = r"\[([\d]*\.[\d]*), ([\d]*\.[\d]*), ([\d]*\.[\d]*)\]"
    string = "[0.0, 6.5, 3.0]"

    results = re.search(pattern, string)

    print(float(results.group(1)), float(results.group(2)), float(results.group(3)))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```